# Conditional probability brain teaser

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**A game is 90% successful in determining a good player. However, 2% of the time it allows a bad
player to pass.
Three people out of a hundred are good players. What is the probability of being a good player
given the game has been passed?**

I was thinking this is a bayesian problem: Probability of being a good player, given the game has been passed:

P(Good player| Game passed) = P(Game passed| Good Player)*P(Good Player)/P(Game passed)

Where:

P(Good Player) = 3/100 = 0.03

P(Game passed) = 1

P(Game passed | Good Player) = 0.9*(1-0.02) = 0.882

So:

**P(Good player| Game passed) = 0.882*0.03/1 = 0.02646**

I was wondering if there was anything wrong in my thought process?

Comment: "A game is 90% successful in determining a good player". How does a game determine a good player?

Comment: Thats all the information i have.
I assume its by a given level of score, where a bad player can achieve 'good player' score purely true luck?

Comment: Try reading it as: "The game is successfully passed, when the player is good, $90\%$ of the time."

Comment: @GrahamKemp That actually makes more sense than my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant events shall be labelled $B$ for bad player, and $G$ for game passed.

We are told:

- A game is 90% successful in determining a good player.

  When the player is good, the game is passed with $90\%$ success rate.

  $$\mathsf P(G\mid B^\complement)=0.90$$
- However, 2% of the time it allows a bad player to pass.

  When the player is bad, the game is passed with $2\%$ success rate.

  $$\mathsf P(G\mid B)=0.02$$
- Three people out of a hundred are good players.

  $$\mathsf P(B^\complement)=0.03$$

Now you can find $\mathsf P(B^\complement\mid G)$ using Bayes' rule and the Law of Total Probability

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.
So 
P(B^c | G) = P(G | B^c) * P(B^c)/P(G)
This gives 0.9*0.03 = 0.027
Since P(G) is = 1 as we know the game has passed?
How do we incorporate the information regarding the test allowing 2% of the time bad players being classified as good players?

Comment: No.  $\mathsf P(G)\neq 1$.  We know that *this* game was passed, however, *not all* games will be passed.  Use the **Law of Total Probability** to evaluate the success rate. @user3788696

Comment: $$P(G)=P(G\cap B)+P(G\cap B^C)=P(G|B)P(B)+P(G|B^C)P(B^C)=(.02)(1-.03)+(.9)(.03)$$